# Опция "Защитить вопрос"

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано

В рамках "инспектирования" ответов новичков столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Автор сознательно искажает русский язык. Объясняю в комментариях,что он неправ. Не понимает.
Правлю ответ (исправляю орфографию). Возвращает свою версию.
Откатываю на свой вариант. Опять возвращает.
Пробую "защитить" вопрос. Не помогает. Все равно демонстративно правит.
(Все флаги модератору давно выставлены, реакции пока нет, но не в этом дело).

Вопроса два.
Основной. Как работает указанная опция "Защитить", почему она не срабатывает против подобного вандализма?
Дополнительный. Что вообще делать в таких случаях? Вроде бы призывают помочь новичку освоится, а как тут поможешь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Защита вопроса никак не влияет на существующие ответы. Она только запрещает новые ответы от участников, пока не набравших 10 очков на этом сайте. См. [справку](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Исправлять неверные ответы не нужно; обычно достаточно указать в комментарии, что ответ неверен, и проголосовать против.

Бывают редкие случаи, когда  ответ выходит за рамки просто неверного, и становится издёвкой ("тролл"). Тогда флаг для модератора вполне уместен. Увы, на данный момент реакции на флаги приходится ждать... и ждать... и ждать...

Хотелось бы больше активности со стороны модераторов (а также большего числа участников проверки низкокачественных ответов — их, кроме Вас, мало кто проверяет).

Comment: Плохо, что не срабатывает как защита от редактирования...

Comment: И да, постоянное манкирование нормами русского языка в угоду какой-то (мифической) политической конъюнктуре - это троллинг, причем злостный.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к [ответу @Yes](/a/25).

Когда возникает война правок и откатов, модератору автоматически прилетает тревога. Поэтому, если модератор на сайте есть, он обратит внимание на происходящее, даже если не обратиться напрямую.

Участвовать в войне правок — скверная затея. Если вы считаете, что пользователь "троллит", то навешиваете тревогу и уходите. Можно подарить минус и оставить комментарий. Нервы дороже.

Бороться с подобным поведением есть возможность только у ромбовых модераторов и выше, простые смертные пользователи, даже обладающие всеми привилегиями, ничего с этим сделать не могут.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Хочу быть "ромбовым".))) А что это такое? Впрочем, пока меня не напрягает.  Там пока всего несколько вопросов - и откат сделать меньше минуты.

Comment: "Ромбовый" - официальный модератор сайта со знаком ромба после ника. Все остальные пользователи с максимальными привелегиями имеют некоторые модераторские привелегии (например "защитить вопрос"), но, к примеру, удалить вопрос они могут только коллективно. Модератор может это сделать единолично.

Comment: @behemothus Если на сайте реально проблемы с недостатком модераторов, то можете поговорить с Николасом, авось повысит вас в должности. Всё-таки вы топовый юзер с большим опытом. Ну или можно выборы провести по всем правилам...

Comment: Немножко не так. Я не рвусь во власть, напротив. И с NCh я часто общался еще на старой платформе... Тут так. Если есть нужда, я всегда готов на какую-то посильную помощь, но хорошо зная себя как лентяя и разгильдяя, не рискую предлагаться  прямо. Желающих, думаю, и без меня хватит. Да и вряд ли  я ему нужен в таком качестве. Короче, он читает - примет к сведенью.